# R Shiny Run a independent process when app is closed

Tags: r, shiny

I have a button that initiates a long process (say a couple of hours) of creating a data pipeline. Is there a way that the user can close the R Shiny app & the process continues to execute.
If needed, i can have a different R script or Python script to run the process

I couldn't think of any ways how this can be done. I'm relatively new to R Shiny

Comment: I think that the way to do that is to have the button click open a terminal and run a separate script in the background, just use Shiny to call the command line action. Here is a conversation about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298462/run-shell-script-in-shiny

Comment: Assuming (a "big" assumption given what we know) that your shiny app is running in a formal shiny environment (e.g., shinyapps.io, Posit Connect, shiny-server, etc), then ... **no**, there is no way to force the process to continue running after the user disconnects and the service managing the shiny app determines that it has exceeded a timeout, pruning/culling the main process. I don't know of any shiny-managing service that supports this (for good reason ... it scales horribly).

Comment: Check library([processx](https://github.com/r-lib/processx)).